# Keras - steps_per_epoch calculation not matching with the ImageDataGenerator output

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, classification, generator

I am working on a basic Classification task with Keras and I seem to have stumbled upon a problem where I need some assistance.

I have 200 samples for training and a 100 for validation, I intend to use a ImageDataGenerator to increase the number of training samples for my task. I want to make sure of the total number of training images that are passed to the fit_generator().

I know that the steps_per_epoch defines the total number of batches we get from a generator and ideally it should be number of samples  divided by the batch size.

However, this is where things do not add up for me. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
num_samples = 200
batch_size = 10
gen = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip = True,
                     vertical_flip = True,
                     width_shift_range = 0.1,
                     height_shift_range = 0.1,
                     zoom_range = 0.1,
                     rotation_range = 10
                    )
x,y = shuffle(img_data,img_label, random_state=2)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.333, random_state=2)
generator = gen.flow(x_train, y_train, save_to_dir='check_images/sample_run')
new_network.fit_generator(generator, steps_per_epoch=len(x_train)/batch_size, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), epochs=1, verbose=2)
```

I am saving the augmented images to see how the images turn out from the ImageDataGenerator and also to ascertain the number of images that are generated from it.

After running this code for a single epoch, I get 600 images in my directory, a number which I cannot arrive at, or maybe I am making a mistake.

Any assistance in making me understand the calculation in this code would be deeply appreciated. Has anyone come across similar problems ?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

gen.flow() creates a NumpyArrayIterator internally and that in turn uses Iterator to calculate the steps_per_epoch. Ideally if steps_per_epoch is None, then the calculation is done as steps_per_epoch = (x.shape[0] + batch_size - 1) // batch_size which is approximately same as your calculation.

Not sure why you see more number of samples. Could you compute the x.shape[0] and double check if your code is as per what you explained?

Comment: Hey￼ ￼￼Aditya, I did that. I noticed that my fit() does not have a batch size and it takes a default of 32. I modified it but still the numbers do not quite add up